# VBA Chart Active Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to create a vba chart from an active cell on a separate sheet. Essentially what I'm trying to do is create a vba chart from an active cell on Sheet 1, all the information resides on a sheet called "Tester" so say i click on cell $C12 on Sheet1 the vba code would then create a chart based off $C12 on the information that lives on "Tester". I would then like that charts destination to be on a Sheet called Analysis. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub createchart()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("tester")


ws.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlBarClustered).Select
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("E" & ActiveCell.Row & ",G" & ActiveCell.Row & ",H" & ActiveCell.Row)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=tester!$E$9,tester!$G$9,tester!$H$9"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesNone)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.ShowCategoryName = False

With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Analysis for " & ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row)
    ActiveChart.HasAxis(xlValue) = False
    ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is unclear as to exactly what you are trying to do and why your recorded code is not working. Charts require data series and selecting a single cell will not give you sufficient data for your chart.  It appears that in your code, you want to select multiple cells but even that is vague.  Fix the question and identify goals and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to achieving your goal, the only issue with your code is that it references the active cell of the active sheet, in your case the worksheet "tester".

What you need to do is get the row reference from sheet1 using a varable and then pass this onto the code that creates the chart:

```
Sub createchart()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("tester")
Dim CellRow As Integer    ' create a variable to hold the cell row

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Select   ' select "sheet1" before we get the active cell row
CellRow = ActiveCell.Row   ' get the row number from the active cell in "sheet1"


ws.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlBarClustered).Select

   'Change the code from ActiveCell.Row to our new variable CellRow
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("E" & CellRow & ",G" & CellRow & ",H" & CellRow)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=tester!$E$9,tester!$G$9,tester!$H$9"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryGridLinesNone)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.ShowCategoryName = False

With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Analysis for " & ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row)
    ActiveChart.HasAxis(xlValue) = False
    ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
End With

End Sub
```